# Create a Document library in SP Online with restricted view

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I need to create a workflow library that has two views, the first allows the Owner to see all documents but the second allows Contributors to see only their own documents.

The second part is easy as I know I can restrict the selection to `[Me]`, but how do I then hide the first view from Contributors?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways, please see which one suits you.

1. You can create SharePoint group for owners and then set it as audience on your first view.
2. Hide default sharepoint webpart from first view and create dedicated webpart page and manage permission on that page, where only owner has access.

Comment: Thanks for coming back Rohit. I am still getting started on SP development so bear with me if you don't mind. Firstly I don't see any option to create or edit an audience for a view. Must this be done in the designer and if so how?  Secondly how do I hide the default webpart? If I add a library to a page, I have the option of setting the default view, but how do I create a page that shows only one view? - Thanks again - Vaughan

Comment: No Designer. For audience, 1. Siteaction 2. Edit Page. 3. Edit webpart. 4. In Advance you should find target audience, chose sharepoint group there which has all the owners.   For dedicated page. 1. Create web part page. 2. Add webpart 3. Selct your Doc library. 3. Edit web part. 4. From view select all items. 5. Now change this Page permission by breaking inheritance. 6. Give read access to only owners.